# How to draw dashed line with GWT's Context2d?

Tags: canvas, gwt

How to draw dashed line with GWT's Context2d? HTML5 canvas has method setLineDash, but GWT's wrapper context2d doesn't seem to have such feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that there is no *out of the box* solution. You need to *go* along the line and draw dashes and gaps.

Example found on [Javatips.net](https://www.javatips.net/api/com.google.gwt.canvas.dom.client.context2d) (Example #17, [source code](https://www.javatips.net/api/skWiki-master/src/gwt/g2d/client/graphics/DashedLineRenderer.java)):

```
/**
     * Draw a dashed line from (fromX, fromY) to (toX, toY).
     * 
     * @param context
     * @param fromX x-coordinate of the starting point
     * @param fromY y-coordinate of the starting point
     * @param toX x-coordinate of the ending point
     * @param toY y-coordinate of the ending point
     * @param dashLength length of the dash
     * @param gapLength length of the gap in between dashes
     */
public static void drawDashedLine(Context2d context, double fromX, double fromY, double toX, double toY, double dashLength, double gapLength) {
    DashedLineHelper checkX = GreaterThanHelper.instance;
    DashedLineHelper checkY = GreaterThanHelper.instance;
    if (fromY - toY > 0) {
        checkY = LessThanHelper.instance;
    }
    if (fromX - toX > 0) {
        checkX = LessThanHelper.instance;
    }
    context.moveTo(fromX, fromY);
    double offsetX = fromX;
    double offsetY = fromY;
    boolean dash = true;
    double ang = Math.atan2(toY - fromY, toX - fromX);
    while (!(checkX.isThereYet(offsetX, toX) && checkY.isThereYet(offsetY, toY))) {
        double len = (dash) ? dashLength : gapLength;
        offsetX = checkX.getCap(toX, offsetX + (Math.cos(ang) * len));
        offsetY = checkY.getCap(toY, offsetY + (Math.sin(ang) * len));
        if (dash) {
            context.lineTo(offsetX, offsetY);
        } else {
            context.moveTo(offsetX, offsetY);
        }
        dash = !dash;
    }
}

/**
 * Helper class for checking the dash line.
 */
private interface DashedLineHelper {

    /**
     * Checks whether the point has been reached yet.
     * 
     * @param from
     * @param to
     * @return
     */
    boolean isThereYet(double from, double to);

    /**
     * Gets the cap of the two values. If the line is increasing, this will
     * return max(v1, v2). If the line is decreasing, this will return
     * min(v1, v2).
     * 
     * @param v1
     * @param v2
     * @return
     */
       double getCap(double v1, double v2);
}

/**
 * Helper for a decreasing line.
 */
private static class LessThanHelper implements DashedLineHelper {
    private static DashedLineHelper instance = new LessThanHelper();

    @Override
    public double getCap(double v1, double v2) {
        return Math.max(v1, v2);
    }

    @Override
    public    boolean isThereYet(double from, double to) {
        return from <= to;
    }       
}

/**
 * Helper for an increasing line.
 */
private static class GreaterThanHelper implements DashedLineHelper {
    private static DashedLineHelper instance = new GreaterThanHelper();

    @Override
    public double getCap(double v1, double v2) {
        return Math.min(v1, v2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isThereYet(double from, double to) {
        return from >= to;
    }       
}
```

Comment: I'm confused - why not just subclass, add the missing jsni method, and cast to the subclass (JSO, so that's permitted)? If the browser already supports it, you can just call into the method. And/or better still, file a bug at https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues so it can be fixed for the next release? Or, is it missing from GWT on purpose, because some canvas-supporting browsers actually don't support that method?

Answer (score 2):

As Colin Alworth pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47906478/how-to-draw-dashed-line-with-gwts-context2d#comment82803148_47914838) you can easily achieve a dashed line by using the built-in line dash functionality of the JavaScript canvas.

First you need to extend GWT's `Context2d` class and add the JSNI method for dashed lines (the `/*-{` and `}-*/` tokens are important here):

```java
import com.google.gwt.canvas.dom.client.Context2d;

public class MyContext2d extends Context2d {

    protected MyContext2d() {}

    public final native void setLineDash(int[] segments) /*-{
        this.setLineDash(segments);
    }-*/;
}
```

Then you can use the `setLineDash()` method of the `Context2d`-extending class in your Java code to configure the dash pattern and it will be displayed in the browser:

```java
Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
MyContext2d context = canvas.getContext2d().cast();
context.setLineDash(new int[]{20, 20, 5, 20});
// draw line etc...
```